# C# - Getters/Setters different from other languages

Tags: c#, asp.net

In Java Getters and setters work like this:

```
public string GetPersonName() {   
  return this.PersonName;  
}
```

In C# it can work the same way, but the thing is i see people are using this syntax

```
public string PersonName { get; set; }
```

Hope anyone will clarify that for me, Thanks !

Comment: Thats the syntax C# has introduced for getter/setter properties. As in Java you dont have to create methods for each getter and setter.

Comment: But this is the only way to make getters and setters in Java from what I know , right? @shahsani

Comment: Yes thats the only way in Java. And C# makes it easy to read/implement the getters/setters using that way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public string PersonName { get; set; }
```

is actually equivalent to

```
private string personName;

public string PersonName
{
     get { return personName; }
     set { personName = value; }
}
```

**Auto-Implemented Properties** were introduced in C# 3.0 to make the code more readable/concise.

Comment: When I want to insert logic into the setter i have to use the 2nd syntax, yes?

Comment: @Dea - Yes, that's correct. You would use the 2nd syntax if you needed to add logic.

Comment: Correct. When your assignment or retrieval logic changes you have to use the 2nd syntax.

Comment: @Shinva - Strictly speaking it's not 100% the same. There is a field, but it's not named `personName` - it's named something like `<PersonName>k__BackingField` (including the `<` and `>` in the name).

Comment: @Enigmativity That is correct. I just used this example as it is easier to explain. If you use ildasm you will see the actual variable names ( with  __BackingField )

Answer (score 3):

Java has not "real" Properties. GetPersonName is a Method and not a "Property".

Consider using a property if the member represents a logical attribute of the type.
Never use a Property for long running Operations!

You should also read this article about Properties in C# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229054(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

That's just a simplified way for less typing. It is called [auto-implemented-properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties)